# Is there anyway to center the menu when using jQuery Mega Drop Down Menu Plugin?

Tags: jquery, layout, menu

I am playing around with [this jquery mega menu plugin](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/examples/) and all of the examples has the menu starting on the left side of the screen.

Is there any way to have this centered so if i have a wide monitor, it will show up in the center horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By editing the CSS you can restyle it to "float" in the middle.  I tested this using firebug on the example linked site.  I had to override the `width` property from `100%` to a fixed width, and then add the `margin: 0 auto`.  The `auto` is the magic to allow it to center itself for a fluid design.

```
#megaMenu { /* This is the ul tag the contains the mega menu */
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you provide an example of your own markup implementing this design we can help you tailor it a little more specifically.  Take a look at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: the issue here is that gets rid of the menu background on the left and right.  I still want the menu background to take up the full width but just center buttons

Comment: You can wrap the `megamenu` in a `div` and then apply the same style background to that div.  Then stretch that div to a `width: 100%`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-plugins/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu/menu.html

If correct you can add additional code using the onLoad parameter, which calculates the margin and sets the menu CSS when the menu has finished initialising. You can get the code either from the demo source code or download the working sample from:

http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-plugins/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-centered.zip

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions that you can make to achieve effect you want. But as you mentions Jquery in tags of this question, I will suggest to do it with **Jquery**.
If you use mega menu plugin like this, for example

```
$('#mega-menu-1').dcMegaMenu({
        rowItems: '3',
        speed: 0,
        effect: 'slide',
        event: 'click',
        fullWidth: true
    });
```

You can add this Javascript after this lines to center your menu.

```
var sum=0;
$('#mega-menu-1 li').each( function(){ sum += $(this).width(); });
$('#mega-menu-1 li:first').css("margin-left",($("#mega-menu-1").width()-sum)/2);
```

This calculates sum of widths of li elements and then add margin from left to your first li element.
If in your page your li elements have some borders or paddings, you can use Jquery's [outerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) function instead of `width()` to calculate that pixels too.
Also thanks for the interesting plugin)

Answer (score 0):

in order to make it work for me I have taken both answers from brombomb and Chuck Norris and combined them with a modification as shown below to avoid 2 problems:

1. no need anymore to set a fixed length in the CSS
2. also works with sub menu items

**CSS**:

```
#megaMenu { /* This is the ul tag the contains the mega menu */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**jQuery** using child selector to sum only main menu items and set then the width:

```
var sum = 0;
$('#megaMenu > li').each(function () { sum += $(this).width(); });
$('#megaMenu').css("width", sum);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set the mega menu to use the full width option - the drop down section will then expand the full width of the menu.

Otherwise the position of the sub-menu is calculated based on the location of the parent link and the available width on the left/right

Comment: I am talking about the top menu (not the sub menu)

Comment: Not without calculating it using something like jquery or having fixed width top menu items.